# Mysql delete statement with limit

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete rows from a table but I get an error.

```
DELETE FROM `chat_messages` ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 20, 50;
```

I get this error at 50:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 50' at line 1

No idea what's wrong.

Comment: Take a look at this question also posted on StackOverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6111961/799653

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You cannot specify offset in `DELETE`'s `LIMIT` clause.

So the only way to do that is to rewrite your query to something like:

```sql
DELETE FROM `chat_messages` 
WHERE `id` IN (
    SELECT `id` FROM (
        SELECT `id` FROM `chat_messages`
        ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
        LIMIT 20, 50
    ) AS `x`
)
```

Supposing that you have primary key `id` column

**UPD**: You need to implement double nesting to fool mysql, since it doesn't allow to select from currently modified table (thanks to Martin Smith)

Comment: MySQL doesn't allow that (Error 1093) unless you add an extra level of nesting. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3271396/73226

Comment: +1 beating me to the answer - `DELETE` accepts `rowcount` only for `LIMIT`.

Comment: @Martin Smith: what do you mean?

Comment: I edited my comment to add further details. If the subquery is directly in the `IN` you get error "You can't specify target table 'chat_messages' for update in FROM clause". You can get around that by making the subquery a derived table.