# deleting variables by specifying id value with OFFSET

Tags: mysql

I want to delete specific variables based on 'id' value. but the code below is displaying syntax error near: OFFSET 1. I use a similar code where I use SELECT instead of DELETE and it works fine, What am doing wrong here? Thanks

```
DELETE  FROM users WHERE name = '$name' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

Comment: please explain your question in more detail.what you are trying??

Comment: I don't believe [`DELETE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) supports the use of the `OFFSET` keyword directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offset component in `LIMIT` is not available in MySQL `DELETE` statements but it ***is*** allowed in `SELECT` statements.

So what you can do to get around this fact, is you can actually join a subselect in a `DELETE` operation, which will then give you your desired results:

```
DELETE a FROM users a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM users
    WHERE name = '$name'
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 1,1
) b ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: oh, sorry did I not accept yours, I thought it was I selected. I have accepted it now.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify offset in DELETE's LIMIT clause.

Simple use:

```
DELETE  FROM users WHERE name = '$name' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: but then it will delete the lowest $name value not the second lowest hence the need for the OFFSET

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142097/mysql-delete-statement-with-limit -- look here.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DELETE  FROM users WHERE name = '$name' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not have OFFSET in [DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) query.

Comment: is there some alternative that will have the same effect?