# MySQL limit clause not accepting 2 arguments

Tags: mysql

I have really searched this and find nothing about this problem.

Very simple query:

```
/*get rid of 125 rows starting at 100*/
delete from my_table WHERE category=5 order by editdate DESC LIMIT 100, 125;
```

This is what is returned:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 125' at line 1
```

I have not used LIMIT in a while, but at the same time I have not had a problem with it.  Error is very mysterious, any ideas?

My version of mysql is 5.x

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot that what I said applies to PostgreSQL only.

Comment: Do you see 'bleem' any where in that query?

Comment: I hope that this answer will help you

[http://stackoverflow.com/a/7142118/4022918][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7142118/4022918

Answer (score 1):

This is because the MySQL syntax for DELETE, doesn't allow a second parameter for LIMIT like in the SELECT case. Please check the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a LIMIT offset on a DELETE command. Here's a way to do it:

```
delete from my_table WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID from my_table WHERE category=5 order by editdate DESC LIMIT 100, 150);
```

Where ID is the primary ID for my_table.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from my_table WHERE category=5 order by editdate DESC LIMIT 125;
```

This will work but you can't use limit like 100,125 . because it shows the selection between rows.