# MySQL Delete All Records Not Selected

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, subquery

I'm trying to delete all entries except the 25 most recent based on the timestamp. I tried this:

```
DELETE FROM `chat` WHERE `IndexNo` NOT IN(SELECT `IndexNo` FROM `chat` ORDER BY `Timestamp` DESC LIMIT 25)
```

That generates this error:

```
#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Which MySQL version are you running?

Comment: Unless I'm very out-of-touch, it really couldn't matter which version they're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not rely on `LIMIT` in `IN/ALL/ANY/SOME` subqueries, but instead you can use multi-delete syntax:

```
DELETE 
  `chat` 
FROM 
  `chat` 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT `IndexNo` FROM `chat` ORDER BY `Timestamp` DESC LIMIT 25) AS `selected`
      ON `chat`.`IndexNo`=`selected`.`IndexNo` 
WHERE 
  `selected`.`IndexNo` IS NULL;
```

-according to [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html), this will work since MySQL 5.0

Answer (score 0):

It is a more general issue about subquery I guess. Try to take a look here: [Problem with LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004129/problem-with-limit-in-all-any-some-subquery)